# Getting distinct list of ints from 2 distinct int lists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 separate queries that are just basic selects, both returning a single distinct column of ints. I need to then combined these 2 lists of ints together to produce a final single distinct list of ints.

Is there any faster way to do this than the following?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM dbo.Test

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM dbo.Test2
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT when it's a UNION. (Since UNION removes all duplicates.)

Comment: Remove `DISTINCT` from the two queries, this what `union` do.

Comment: @vpk: `union all` is indeed faster than `union` but it's not eliminating duplicate values :-)

Comment: @dnoeth.correct. i was wrong in missing the `distinct` part of the question

Comment: Which one is actually faster, `SELECT DISTINCT ... UNION SELECT DISTINCT ...` or  `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...` depends on the actual data :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have duplicates within each table, then the following is probably faster:

```
select id
from dbo.test
union all
select id
from dbo.test1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from dbo.test t where t.id = t1.id);
```

For this, you want an index on `test(id)`.

Even with duplicates, the following is likely to be faster:

```
select distinct id
from dbo.test
union all
select distinct id
from dbo.test1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from dbo.test t where t.id = t1.id);
```

This requires indexes for both `test(id)` and `test1(id)`.  The idea is that the indexes are scanned to return the id.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the fastest approach in your case is to remove the two `DISTINCT` since `UNION` will remove all duplicates overall anyway:

```
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.Test

UNION

SELECT ID
FROM dbo.Test2
```

Note that the two `DISTINCT`s don't ensure uniqueness across both sequences anyway, that's what the `UNION` does. If you don't need/want unique elements use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily faster.  If the two tables have an index on `id`, I'm not sure if SQL Server will use the index for duplicate removal.  This could have a big impact on performance, if each table has lots of duplicates.